# Relative Path not working in ArcMap and ArcObjects

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, mxd, file-path

I'm using ArcMap 10.0 and Windows 7 64 bit. I'm trying to set a relative paths for my MXD file. My MXD is located at `C:\workspace\rastertest.mxd` and the data is located at `C:\workstation\data\testdted.dt2`.

When I set Relative Path to true in ArcMap's Document Properties or in ArcObjects using `IMapDocument.SaveAs(true, true)` the new raster data source will point to `C:\Users\tester\AppData\Local\Temp\data`.

Do you know what could be causing this? I would like to eventually move around the MXD file and Rasters and keeping the same directory hierarchy.

Also, when I run ArcMap 10.0 on a Windows XP machine the relative paths work correctly.

Comment: Do you use XTools Pro 8.0?